# How do I prove that the following sets are Borel sets?

Tags: borel-sets, measurable-sets

I have the following problem.

> Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Borel-measurable functions. Show that
> $$\{x|\limsup\, f_n(x)=\infty\}, \,\,\{x|\limsup \,f_n(x)=c\}, c\in \mathbb{R}$$ are borel sets.

From the lecture we just know that since $f_n$ are Borel-measurable, then also $g(x)=\limsup \,f_n(x)$ is Borel-measurable.
I only looked at the second set for the moment and I thought if $g(x)$ is measurable, we get that $g^{-1}(c)=\{x|g(x)=c\}\subset B(\mathbb{R})$. Remark that $c\in B(\mathbb{R})$.
But I'm not sure if this works because somehow I found it too easy.

Comment: You know that $\text{limsup}f_n^{-1}(c)$ is borel for every $n$ and every $c\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ what can you say about the union in $n$ of this sets?

Comment: As I claimed above $g^{-1}(c)$ is an element of $B(\mathbb{R})$ and since this is a sigma algebra the union over all n and all c are also in $B(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: is this correct so? If yes, I can't look at the inverse image of $\infty$  what should I do in this case?

Comment: Depends on how you handled the proof that $\text{limsup}f_n$ is Borel-measurable but if you notice that the fact that $\text{limsup}f_n(x)=\infty$ is a possibility then $\text{limsup}f_n^{-1}(\infty)$ is well defined on the one-point compactification $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$. That could be a way of "convincing" yourself that it makes sense, you can also explicitly show that $\{x:\text{limsup}f_n(x)=\infty\}$ is Borel by approximating it by $\varepsilon$ sets as $A_\varepsilon:=\{x:\text{limsup}f_n(x)>\varepsilon\}$.